# Automate 'Right click' and 'Save Target as' in VB

Tags: javascript, vb.net, save, basic

I am working on a program for downloading bills that will automatically navigate to a webpage using the web browser object, log into it, navigate to the Bills page and download the most recent bill.

It all works well up until where I actually download it, as using the invokemember("click") code fires up IE and asks me to log in again which is not what I want to do. The DownloadFile method also does not work, and downloads a file that says the object has been moved to he login URL.

Right clicking and selecting "save target as" from the web browser works, but I'm not sure how to go about automating it.

Edit: Here's the code for the downloading part, parts of it were borrowed from another question on here but I can't remember who or where.

Dim IsRightElement As Boolean = False

```
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In Browser.Document.Links()

        If curElement.GetAttribute("InnerText") = "Download Call Charges" Then
            IsRightElement = True
        End If

        If IsRightElement Then

            Dim Link As String = curElement.DomElement.href.ToString()

            'This is where I'm stuck
            'My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(Link, "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PhoneBill.csv", "<username>", "<password>")
            'The above does not work

            'curElement.InvokeMember("contextmenu")
            'Not sure what to do here



            IsRightElement = False
            Exit For
        End If

    Next
    Me.Close()
```

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: Code added to original post.